# Problems with http post method, HttpServletResponse and cookies on java

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

At the beginning i was sending a redirect with the cookies set on HttpServletResponse but later i decided to not redirect and only get the information gave from the servlet but the problem is i can't set the cookies on this post method.

So i would like to know how to set cookies with postmethod and if there is a way to process the cookies that are in HttpServletResponse

```
String temp=null;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Oauth Data Requester");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(ADDRESS+"/SampleProvider");
    //Aqui ainda enviamos o XML inteiro como parametro
    method.addParameter("p", "\"java2s\"");
    try{
      int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
      if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
        System.err.println("no post method found");
      } else {
         temp=method.getResponseBodyAsString();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
      method.releaseConnection();
      if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In servlets, you can get all cookies sent by the client using [`HttpServletRequest#getCookies()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29).

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
// ...
```

And you can set cookies on the response using [`HttpServletResponse#addCookie()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29).

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie(name, value));
```

---

In HttpClient 3.x (I assume that you're using 3.x, because the `executeMethod()` method isn't present on 4.x anymore), you can add cookies to the `HttpState` and then set it on `HttpClient` *before* executing the method.

```
HttpState state = new HttpState();
state.addCookie(new Cookie(".example.com", "name", "value"));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.setState(state);
// ...
```

After executing the method, you can get the (updated) cookies by

```
Cookie[] cookies = client.getState().getCookies();
// ...
```

Comment: tks for the asw i ll tru it now :) stange i'm using 4.1.1 not 3... do u know any good tuturial about this area ?

Comment: Probably your classpath is polluted with a 3.x one and/or you didn't put 4.x in the classpath at all. As to the tutorials, there are several guides at HttpComponents site. http://hc.apache.org/

Comment: you are right i have i have commons.httpclient 3.X on my libs :P is that bad ? should i go to 4.x ? by the way probably this import javax.servlet.http.Cookie; was giving this example problems i had to set the lib that i want to use state.addCookie(new Cookie(".example.com", "name", "value")); -> state.addCookie(new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie(".example.com", "name", "value"));

Comment: It's not bad. It's just a newer version. As to the classname conflict, well, move it to its own class without any `javax.servlet` imports.

Comment: thx a lot for the help :) it's a bit late but tomorrow i ll try !

Comment: BalusC, thanks for this answer, but I got a question. Is it necessary to set the cookies in the request to get the updated cookies back in the response after the method is executed? I mean, does `client.getState().getCookies();` return  the response cookies regardless of whether cookies were set in the request before executing the method or not?